# Drupal: set active class on primary links menu depending on path or content type

Tags: drupal, menu

I have some styling based on the primary links active class. I would like to set the class of a link in the primary links to active (`<a class="active"...>`) based on either the content type or the path.

I have already done some research on this but haven't yet seen anything that seems to match my query.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Same question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11129/how-to-set-a-menu-item-active/36526 (how do you set a duplicate?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contributed module [Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/menutrails) is what you're looking for. You can then set a menu trail based on content type.

Comment: Hi Fabian, 

Thanks for your answer. That sounds like it'll solve my problem. I guess I was kinda hoping someone might show me how to do it using theme_links() or similar and I might learn something!

Ben

Answer (score 0):

check out [context](http://drupalmodules.com/module/context) module (development seed). It gives you a nice interface to set a context for your site or section within. 
You can have a news section with the path "news/node-title" and context would set the news menu item active. It does a lot's of cool things beyond this, like granular block management.

Parts of contexts concept will merge into D8 menu/routing system. ;)

Regards

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. I did have a look at the context module. It looked quite complex. Or in other words take me longer to implement than menu trails. If I'm in a similar position again, i will certainly consider using it.